# How to skip a div and select all in selenium find_element(By.XPATH)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to select and copy all the text in a div, except H1 tag. The text looks as shown image.[image]

To select all content, I could do by using the below code

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")  #select all
```

But when I try to avoid the H1 tag content, which is "Do You Have Dry Pack...", with it's corresponding div which is

```
"//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1"
```

with the code like below, it's showing error

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"[not(("//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1"))]).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")  #select all
```

The error is
[image]

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Can you share the HTML in text format for that h1 tag and in and around elements which you are trying to copy?

Comment: it's not exactly taken from a html. the html is dynamically generated during a big program.

Comment: Even if it's dynamically generated, to answer your question, We'd need HTML to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use `//` to `Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are`. [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Secondly, about your error, you define a string in JS with double quotes, but there are double quotes in your string. Therefore, you have to escape those with character `\`. For e.g:

```js
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div\"[not((\"//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1"))]).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
```

Lastly, instead of using element's index (e.g: `div[2]`), you should find another way to define the unique path to that element. Element's id, class, attributes are commonly used. In case that didn't work, you can use `//` to reach the child nodes, then use `..` to reach their parent.

Comment: sorry, I don't really get what you are saying

Comment: Ok, firstly, your xpath `"//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1"` might become `"//*[@id='__next']//h1"`. You might want to check if it's the right element.

Comment: And about your error, you define a string in JS with double quotes, but there are double quotes in your string. Therefore, you have to escape those with character "\". For e.g: `browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div\"[not((\"//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/h1"))]).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")`

Comment: I tried both, but no effect

Answer (score 0):

With that xpath you are getting the entire div, but when you put the "not" you are telling: "take me all the divs that hasn't a h1 inside". But you want to exclude only the h1 so you need to **take the elements INSIDE THE DIV**, not the div. You can do that with this xpath:

**/div/*[not(self::h1)]**

```
//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/*[not(self::h1)]
```

Then in the code you have to get this as a list, not a single element.

And please, try to create more clean and less dangerous xpaths as the other answer said, something like: `//*[@id='__next']//h1` it's better.

Comment: browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/*[not(self::h1)]").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")

Comment: I tried like this as you suggested, but still it's selecting the entire(not excluding the h1)

Comment: because control + a select everything,you have to find another way to select the text.

Comment: but if you only want to copy the text, why don't do that with getText()?

Comment: getText() will work to copy text, but I want the content with all the sub headings except the <h1>

Comment: So get the list of all the elements (without h1) and use getText()........................

Comment: How will that work? using getText() itself will remove all the tags